# Bounding $2^{\aleph_\omega}$ without PCF theory

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

Via PCF theory, we can prove in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ alone that if $\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit cardinal then $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\aleph_{\omega_4}$. However, PCF theory is rather complicated. I'm curious whether there is a "toy" version of PCF theory - or an entirely different argument - which can prove any bound at all on $2^{\aleph_\omega}$ under the assumption that $\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit cardinal.

To make this more precise, is there a simpler way than PCF theory to prove the following in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ **alone**?

> If $\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit cardinal, then $2^{\aleph_\omega}$ is less than the least weakly inaccessible.

(Recall that a weakly inaccessible cardinal is a regular limit cardinal - in particular, in contrast with strong accessibility if $\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible we may still have $\lambda<\kappa\le 2^\lambda$. So the fact above isn't trivial.)

Comment: I was not aware that PCF is strictly stronger than ZFC

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It's not - did I say it was? (Hence the beginning: "Via PCF theory, we can prove in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ alone ...".)

Comment: If it is not, than the proof you know is a proof "in ZFC alone". While certainly someone may come up with an elegant proof that "obviously" does not use PCF, it is logically impossible to prove a statement that there is no simpler way when ZFC minus PCF is not properly definieable

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm confused, this seems needlessly pedantic. I'm asking whether there's a simpler way to prove a weaker result. Yes, that's a somewhat vague question, but I think it's well within the bounds of an appropriate question for MSE. (Or do you really object to all questions which make reference to specific techniques on the grounds that those techniques are not themselves formally defined?)

Comment: Quick proof: Suppose it wasn't, then it was greater than $\aleph_{\omega_4}$, in direct contradiction with Shelah's famous result. $\square$

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sigh. Is this really that bad a question?

Comment: No, it's a nice question. I'm not sure how to even approach something like that, though. I don't know if it was even known before Shelah. I'd think it's a far better idea to ask this on MO instead of here, but you can also give it a few days.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, sorry, I thought you were implicitly agreeing with Hagen's comments. Yeah, I debated posting this to MO but I wasn't certain that I wasn't missing something fairly elementary. I'll wait a few days and then move it over, it's certainly not urgent on my end.

Comment: I mean, you can probably put some ad-hoc version of Shelah's proof into a forcing package, but is that what you're really asking for?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Would it actually be simpler? In fact, I'd love it if there were a rephrasing of the argument in terms of forcing which trimmed away some technicality at the expense of a worse upper bound.

Comment: I'm just spitballing here, I don't know if it's simpler or what...

Comment: How would you expected a *forcing* based proof to look like, by the way? (I've only brought forcing up because you used the [tag:forcing] tag...)

Comment: If I remember correctly, Tom Jech published a paper a while ago in which he developed just enough PCF theory to prove the $\aleph_{\omega_4}$ result. That doesn't answer the question, because it's still PCF theory, but it does simplify things.